# Run a shell script on all files within a directory and its sub-directories

Tags: unix, shell

Good evening fellow computational authors,

I'm trying to run the following script:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec /search_replace.sh {} \;
```

so that it runs search_replace.sh on all the .php files in a folder and its sub-folders. I keep on getting the error:

```
find: /search_replace.sh: No such file or directory
```

Any assistance?

Comment: All the scripts are in the same folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
/search_replace
```

to

```
./search_replace
```

or whatever the full path to the script is...

Comment: Additionally, he'll want to use -type f